# How to perform actions on innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This should be some easiest of solution, though I am unable to find anything related. Using jQuery if I contain an element into a variable like:

```
var myContainer = $(body).find('.any-class');
```

Now this variable is an object, which contains all the data in its respective elements. It has its own methods (like `myContainer.attr('anyAttr')` will not work, but `myContainer.getAttribute('anyAttr')` will work now).

My query is when I get `myContainer.innerHTML`, then I am unable to perform operations on that like - `.find()`. I require this as I need to find classes and ids in `innerHTML` of that element(which I actually created at run-time).

This flow is important as I am looping within each class. Here is my code:

```
var myContainer = $(body).find('.any-class');
$.each(myContainer, function(key, value) {
    if (value.getAttribute('is_required')) {
        //value.innerHTML.find('.anyOtherClass'); find doesn't work. What should be done?
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use find while creating variable myContainer...
As you cannot find any element which is present in a variable which contains html...

Comment: have you tried `value.find()`? I don't think you need the `innerHTML` part. also, will `#anyId` occur multiple times? Because that in itself will be a contradiction, as *id* is a unique selector, so it will only find the instance of `#anyId` once every time.

Comment: @Martin value.find() not working either as it is an object now, rather than DOM element. and id was just an example, it could be a class as well. I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the type of `innerHTML` is string, you can not implement `find()` on that. You can simply use `value` as a jQuery object like `$(value).find()`.

Please Note: You have to enclose `body` with quotes.

```js
var myContainer = $('body').find('.any-class');
$.each(myContainer, function(key, value) {
  if (value.getAttribute('is_required')) {
    console.log(typeof(value.innerHTML)); //string
    console.log($(value).find('.anyOtherClass')[0]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="any-class" is_required="yes">
  <span>Container 1</span>
  <span class="anyOtherClass">Container 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that is 'myContainer', I mistyped it, and yes using $(value).find() works. I was previously doing value.find(). Does using $() makes it work as a DOM element?

Comment: @Anant, since the intended `find()` is a jQuery method, you have to use `value` as a jQuery object and yes, it is still a DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the `.innerHTML` and wrap your element with jQuery if `value` is a DOM HTML element:

```
$(value).find('#anyId')....
```

Please be aware of the return types and the exact meaning of the functions you call and properties you get. Calling [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) on `$(body)` returns a jQuery list, wrapped HTML elements, all of which match your selector expression. For such lists jQuery indeed provides other methods like `http://api.jquery.com/attr/`.

In your example you are suddenly switching to another variable `optionContainers`, okay, ignoring the previous line, you are now iterating with [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) over an array-like object and processing its indexed entries.
If `optionContainers` is a jQuery list, this indeed retrieves the DOM HTML elements.
To use jQuery methods you have to wrap those elements with jQuery.

Always remember jQuery is only providing an extra layer of features so you have to make sure you are always talking with that layer - just as if you were talking with somebody via a lawyer (who offers several high level services).

Answer (score 0):

If the action has to be performed on all elements with attribute 'required', then you may try

```
document.querySelectorAll('[attributeName="attributeValue"]');
```

In case of selecting all that are required, you may use below

```
document.querySelectorAll("[required]");
```

You can change your code to the following:

```
var selectedElements = value.querySelectorAll("required");
```

Now you can loop through the selectedElements with a forEach or a for loop

Documentation on querySelectorAll : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll